# Angular 7 populate dropdown list by previously selected item id

Tags: material-design, angular7, dropdown

I'm new to angular 7 material design and I'm working on a multi drop down list.

So I have 2 dropdown lists in total where the second one requires the id of the first.

This is so that the list of items in the second dropdown would narrow down based on the previously selected item. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, and any help is much appreciated.

> service

```
   getAllMarkets(){
   return this.http.get(this.url + 'allMarkets')
  }

   getProducts(id: number){
   return this.http.get(this.url + 'products')
  }
```

> .ts

```
markets;
products;

ngOnInit() {
this.getMarkets();
this.getFilteredProducts();
}

getMarkets() {
return this.service.getAllMarkets().subscribe(res => {
this.markets = res;
});
}

getFilteredProducts() {
return this.service.getProducts(Not sure how to pass id).subscribe(res => {
this.products = res;
});
}
```

> .html

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Markets" [(ngModel)]="selectedMarket" name="market">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let market of markets" [value]="market.id" >
          {{market.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Products" [(ngModel)]="selectedProducts" name ="product">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let product of products" [value]="product.id"
          >
            {{product.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, will this allow me to pass the id to the second dropdown list?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the first list to selectedMarket with ngModel so

```
this.service.getProducts(this.selectedMarket)
```

and set this.products = [] to clear the list before the call to get products.

and on the call it on ngModelChange

```
<mat-select placeholder="Markets" [(ngModel)]="selectedMarket" name="market" (ngModelChange)="getFilteredProducts()">
```

Comment: Hi Adrian, unfortunately, that hasn't worked for me. I can't populate the second drop down list. Where would I be placing `this.products=[]`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to capture the selected value of the first `mat-select` with (change) like:

```
<mat-select placeholder="Markets" [(ngModel)]="selectedMarket" name="market" (change)="onSelectMakert($event.value)">
```

Then, you should declare the onSelectMakert(event) in your component in order to get the selected value of the first `mat-select`. Once you have declared the function, let's load the second select.

```
onSelectMakert(data) {
        this.products = // charge your products base on the "data" (aka. id)
    }
```

Comment: Hi German! Thank you for your feedback. how would `onSelectMakert(data) {
        this.products = // charge your products base on the "data" (aka. id)
    }` look like? Would it look like this => `onSelectMakert(data) {
        this.products = this.selectedMarket
    }` ? I can't seem to get it to work.